# C# automatic properties do not access the fields

Tags: c#, properties

So I've got a Point class. It got x,y and z fields.
I've implemented my overloaded constructor as such:

```
public Point(int x, int y, int z)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    Z = z;
}
```

The capitals are my properties implemented automatically.

```
public int X { get ; set; }
public int Y { get ; set; }
public int Z { get ; set; }
```

So here's the problem. When I instantiate a Point object

```
Point p = new Point(2, 3, 4);
```

and output the X, Y and Z properties I get that they are all zero!. So I changed the constructor to change the _z field directly instead of using the property.
 I ran the visual studio with a breakpoint and saw that

_x = 0

_y = 0

_z = 0

X = 2

Y = 3

Z = 4

What am I missing about the role of the automatic properties ?
This is related to the warning i keep getting that the fields are not being used whenever I use the automatic properties, right?

note: Am i using the term field correctly ? I've got a modest c++ knowledge, and they are the same as the private data members right ?!

EDIT:
Thanx guys for the feedback and sorry for not being clear enough.

```
private int _x, _y, _z;
public Point(int x, int y, int z)
{
   X = x;    
   Y = y;    
   Z= z;
}
```

So these are my fields(assuming field means private data members)
and my overloaded constructor.
the previous visual studio output was BEFORE I changed the the constructor(sorry abt that)
Now when I changed the constructor to change the _z directly like this

```
public Point(int x, int y, int z)
    {
       X = x;    
       Y = y;    
       this._z= z;
    }
```

this is the output

_x = 0

_y = 0

_z = 4

X = 2

Y = 3

Z = 0

Comment: you have just `get` & `set` for all properties and you are assigning values to these properties from `constructor`. So you get same result. But where is your complete `class`? Where are you assigning values to `fields`?

Comment: can you show some more code

Comment: what do you mean changed the constructor to change the `_z` field directly?  Are you showing ALL your code?

Comment: I think it must be a typo somewhere. The code looks good. Are you sure you typed X = x and not x = x?

Comment: When you say, "It got x,y and z fields," do you really mean "_x, _y, and _z"?  Are you saying that you expect setting the X, Y, and Z properties to automatically set some fields in your class called _x, _y, and _z?  Your question as it stands is very confusing.

Comment: What are `_x`, `_y` and `_z`? They don't exist in the code you posted...

Comment: If you defined automatic properties, then you don't have fields. That's the point.

Comment: Mustafa please show the entire class and the code that calls it.

Comment: Works perfectly fine here... http://pastie.org/9280140

Comment: When you use automatically implemented properties, the **compiler** creates the backing fields *for you*. You don't have to declare the fields yourself - and if you do, they will always be unrelated to the fields that the automatically implemented properties provide.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are checking fields which are never used, they are not related to your properties.

So either don't use auto-implemented properties but use your backing fields instead

```
private int _x;
private int _y;
private int _z;

public Point(int x, int y, int z)
{
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
    _z = z;
}

public int X 
{
    get { return _x; }
    set { _x = value; }
}
public int Y
{
    get { return _y; }
    set { _y = value; }
}
public int Z
{
    get { return _z; }
    set { _z = value; }
}
```

or remove the fields and use only the auto-implemented properties

```
public int X { get ; set; }
public int Y { get ; set; }
public int Z { get ; set; }
```

I always use the former approach because the latter  needs to be changed later often, for example if i want to add logic or change access.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use private fields in your properties then implement your properties like this :

```
public class Point
{
    private int _x;
    private int _y;
    private int _z;

    public Point(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Z = z;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get { return this._x; }
        set { this._x = value; }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return this._y; }
        set { this._y = value; }
    }

    public int Z
    {
        get { return this._z; }
        set { this._z = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me that this is what the OP wants to do. It sounds more like they want the auto-implemented properties to work.

Comment: @MarcGravell, thanks for your observation, but I think he told _x = 0 that means he want to update the private field value of property.

Comment: @MarcGravell can't estimate what OP actually wants, since OP not yet interacted. But this might be the expectation from OP.

Comment: Marc Gravell is correct. I want my auto implemented properties to work (I'm kinda infatuated with their simplicity coming from c++ :))

Comment: @Mustafa As Marc stated in a comment to the question, the backing fields for auto-implemented properties are not available at design-time.  They are generated by the compiler and are only available through reflection (or possibly `dynamic` - I haven't tried it and would urge against it).  So either use the property names directly or change the getters and setters to use the "custom" backing fields.

Comment: @DStanley Yeah, Marc's answer was the most helpful. I did not know the first thing about auto-implemented properties and that explains it. Thanx